# How to filter out multiple scores from users to get 15 top scores from 15 differnt users

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to query for 15 scores from a table, in a lowest score to highest score order and filtering out a user from appearing multiple times in the result. So that in the end there is a list of 15 scores from 15 different users.

I am still quite new to SQLAlchemy/Flask-SQLAlchemy, so apologies if the answer is obvious.

So far I got my code to either filter by lowest to highest score when I remove the line with `scores = scores.order_by(Scores.user_id).distinct(Scores.user_id)`, or filter out a user from appearing multiple times with the code you see below. But I cannot do both at the same time with a `.distinct(Scores.user_id)` query.

My current code looks as such using Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy:

```
@blueprint.route("/")
def index():
    # This is for filtering of scores from different levels and game versions
    diff_arg = request.args.get("diff", 0)
    ver_arg = request.args.get("ver", GAME_VERSION)
    user_arg = request.args.get("user", None)

    scores = Scores.query

    if not user_arg:
        scores = scores.order_by(Scores.user_id).distinct(Scores.user_id)
    else:
        if user := Users.query.filter_by(username=user_arg).first():
            scores = scores.filter_by(user_id=user.id)
        else:
            abort(404, "User not found")

    if ver_arg:
        scores = scores.filter_by(version=ver_arg)

    scores = (
        scores.filter_by(difficulty=diff_arg)
        .order_by(Scores.score.asc())  # This doesnt seem todo anything
        .limit(MAX_TOP_SCORES)         # I assume its because I filter_by user for distinct
        .all()
    )

    # and return some stuff to render out a template
    return render_template(
        "views/scores.html",
        scores=scores,
        diff=int(diff_arg),
        ver=ver_arg,
        user=user_arg
    )
```

If this is also important the database I'm using is Postgresql running on Docker along with the Flask app

Comment: How many users do you have compared to how many scores?

Comment: @JonSG sorry but I don't have any numbers yet, since its for a college project and not finished

Comment: Well in general I would either take the scores sorted from best to worse and iterate over them until I saw 15 unique users or more likely, I would select the max score grouped by user then sort that by the returned max score if that helps

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit I got it working with a subquery

```
@blueprint.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    diff_arg = request.args.get("diff", 0)
    ver_arg = request.args.get("ver", GAME_VERSION).strip()
    user_arg = request.args.get("user", "").strip()

    scores = db.session.query(Scores).filter_by(difficulty=diff_arg)

    subquery = (
        db.session.query(Scores.user_id, func.min(Scores.score).label("min"))
        .group_by(Scores.user_id)
        .subquery()
    )

    if ver_arg:
        scores = scores.filter_by(version=ver_arg)

    if not user_arg:
        scores = scores.join(subquery, Scores.user_id == subquery.c.user_id).filter(
            Scores.score == subquery.c.min
        )
    else:
        user = Users.query.filter_by(username=user_arg).first()
        if user:
            scores = scores.filter_by(user_id=user.id)
        else:
            abort(404, "User not found")

    scores = scores.order_by(Scores.score.asc()).limit(MAX_TOP_SCORES).all()

    return render_template(
        "views/scores.html",
        scores=scores,
        diff=int(diff_arg),
        ver=ver_arg,
    )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).